# Adding white space after input?

Tags: html, css

I have this kind of html

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox">
Print document
</label>
```

The problem is that Print document text is alwats sticed to check box?
I can not add Print Document in new element, of controller, is it possible to do that 
is simple CSS rule?

Comment: You need some variation of `input { margin-right: 20px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct html is : `<input type="checkbox"><label>Print document</label>`

After you can select in css the checkbox like this :

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: The OP's HTML is correct. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label): `The HTML <label> Element represents a caption for an item in a user interface. It can be associated with a control either by placing the control element inside the label element, or by using the for attribute.`

Answer (score 2):

Add CSS :

```
input[type=checkbox]{
padding-right : 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb49R/2/)**

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<label>
    Print document
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: @user3165604 do you mean you can't change the html?

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin in style:

Inline CSS:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:15px;">
Print document
</label>
```

Internal CSS:

```
<head>
<style>
input[type=checkbox]{
margin-right: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:15px;">
Print document
</label>
```

External CSS:

style.css

```
input[type=checkbox]{
margin-right: 15px;
}
```

page.html

```
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:15px;">
Print document
</label>
```

Demo:

[Inline CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/rTMUn/)

[Internal CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/rTMUn/1/)

[External CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/rTMUn/2/)